# exceljs error when reading csv file uploaded from windows

Tags: node.js, express, multer, exceljs

When uploading csv file created by windows; an error is generated when trying to parse the file using exceljs.

Here is the error message:

```
message: "Can't find end of central directory : is this a zip file ? 
If it is, see https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/howto/read_zip.html"
```

Answer (score -1):

It happens because of the uploading stage, you haven't uploaded the file successfully so that can not reading later. Please double check whether you uploading or having the file on cloud storage successfully or not